# Как создать XML и сжать его?

Tags: php

Создаю xml таким образом

```
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; ++$i) {
        $track = $xml->addChild('track');
        $track->addChild('path', "song$i.mp3");
        $track->addChild('title', "Track $i - Track Title");
    }

    Header('Content-type: text/xml');
    print($xml->asXML());
```

Как далее мне его сжать , чтобы он имел формат `text.xml.gz` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Имя файла, который мы сжимаем
$file = "test.xml";

// Имя создаваемого gz-файла
$gzfile = "test.gz";

// Открытие gz-файла (w9 - самое высокое сжатие)
$fp = gzopen($gzfile, 'w9');

// Сжатие файла
gzwrite($fp, file_get_contents ($file));

// Закрытие gz-файла
gzclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
umask(0);
exec("gzip -k " . $path . "text.xml");
exec("chmod 755 ".. $path . "text.xml.gz");
```